# DELL B1260dn printer Linux open-source driver

Tags: linux, printing

I have a DELL B1260dn printer and it works on Linux.

But it works with a closed-source driver.

Indeed, my driver seems to be a variant of this one:

http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/

I have downloaded the "B1260dn_Linux_v1.03_Driver.tar.gz" archive on the DELL website.

Then I have extracted it to copy these files :

1. Linux/i386/pstospl -> /usr/lib/cups/filter
2. Linux/i386/libscmssc.so -> /usr/lib
3. Linux/noarch/at_opt/share/ppd/B1260dn.ppd -> /usr/share/cups/model
4. Linux/noarch/at_opt/share/utils/SetIPApplet.html -> /usr/share/b1260dn
5. Linux/noarch/at_opt/share/utils/SetIPApplet.jar -> /usr/share/b1260dn

The 1) file is required for CUPS (only the binary is available !).

The 2) file is a dependency of 1) (only the binary is available !).

The 3) file is the PPD file for CUPS.

The 4) file is an HTML file that is using 5) and can be read into your web browser (using the Java plugin).

The 5) file is a Java application (only the binary is available !) allowing to set the IP address of the printer.

As you can see we have a lot of binaries, so it is closed-source.

I would like to find an open-source alternative.

I have found this:

http://www.openprinting.org/driver/splix/

But unfortunately I have not yet found the way to compile it correctly.

Do you have any software in mind ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same printer (attached via Network [RJ45]) and the generic driver suggested by Ubuntu 12.04 (64 Bit) does its job. It prints single and double sided on demand – although I did not test the effect of different level of toner (like "fast draft" or "best quality").

See here what I mean with generic suggested driver (mind that I am using Ubuntu):

1. Type and select "Printing" within the dash
2. Click "Add" (the green plus)
3. Click on "Network printer"
4. Wait a moment until the printer magically appears and select it, then click forward (make sure "AppSocket/JetDirect network printer via DNS-SD" is selected too)
5. Wait while ubuntu is looking for drivers and then in the "Choose Driver" dialog select "Generic (Recommended)" – click forward
6. Keep "PCL 6/PCL XL (recommended)" and the option "Foomatic/pxlcolor [en]" selected
7. Now name the printer as you wish and everything should be fine now.

Kind regards.